# Render Partial view with Reloaded content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, caching, reload, renderpartial

I'm Working with Asp .Net Mvc3,following is my jQuery,

```
$('#ddlVertical').change(function () {
    var vertical = $("#ddlVertical").val();
    $.get("Vertical", {
        "vertical": $.trim(vertical)
    },

    function (data) {
        $("#Vertical").html(data);
    })
});
```

when i change the dropdown old data getting loaded.i want the Partial view to get loaded with new data.when changing dropdown the page should get reloaded.how can i do this?

Comment: Can you show your controllers code?

Comment: public ActionResult Vertical(string vertical = null)
        {            AssoModel objAssoModel = new AssoModel();
            try
            {          objAssoModel=objAssoModel.GetVerticalAccessDetailvertical);
            return PartialView("Vertical", objAssoModel);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {   ILogManager LogManager = new LogManager();
                var frame = new StackFrame(0);
                LogManager.CallLogging(frame, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                return RedirectToAction("Error", "Common");
            }
        }

Comment: while changing dropdown option the viewpage displays the values from cache once i refresh the page only i'm getting the updated value how can i perform this refresh the page using code